# Excel vba macro for that copy from 1 word-wraped cell to multiple multiple cells

Tags: excel, line-breaks, vba

At work I often have to copy large amounts information from one sheet to another (Excel 2007).
The problem is that I want to copy a row on sheet1 that contains word wrapped text with line-breaks to multiple cells on sheet2 like in the example below.

Sheet1 looks like this (but with 50-200 rows):

```
Row    A          B          C       D       E      F....
1      PN         Name       Task

2      1-234      Text1      Text2
                             is word-
                             wrapped

3      2-345      Text3      Text4
                             Text5
```

and I want to write a macro that helps me to copy this information to sheet2 so that I get a new row for each line-break.
Sheet2 should look like this:

```
Row    A          B          C        D       E      F....

1      PN         Name       Task

2      1-234      Text1      Text2

3      1-234      Text1      is word-

4      1-234      Text1      wrapped

5      2-345      Text3      Text4

6      2-345      Text3      Text5
```

In other words I want to create a new row for each task in column C

Can anyone give me some pointers.
I often have to do this late at night and I can’t go to bed until I copied all the rows.

Thanks!

Comment: lol at the `can't go to bed until I copied all the rows`. ok now, what have you tried? Have you tried to record a macro? what version excel are you using

Comment: Im using excel 2007 and I have tried to record a macro but I cant get a recorded macro to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can help better later, but for now, just hints:

Set a Range variable to column C:

`Dim DataColumn as Range`

`Set DataColumn = Sheet1.Range("C:C")`

Set a `row index = i` from 1 to the end (until A column is empty). Increase this `i` every internal loop, as following.

Do a `while loop` since your end line will vary (you will be inserting lines)

Inside the loop, get the `DataColumn.Rows(i).Value`. Store it in a variable as string

Do an internal loop to find all linebreak characters in the value:
Search for the first line break character (I believe its `Chr(10)`) in that Value (I believe it's the `InStr(text)` vba method)
If not found, end this internal loop

If found
Get the `Left(text)` part of the text before the first line break character. Substitute the line value for that left part. (First time you don't add lines)
Remove that part from the stored value (use the `Right(text)` for that).
Next loop iteration, search for the linebreak again. 
This time, you will be adding lines at `i` row index. (`DataColumn.Rows(i).EntireRow.Insert`)

Copy all the data from the previous line and put into this new one, use the left part of the text at C column.

Reapeat until no linebreaks found, and go forth.